# Sending a post request from Backbone.js is returning a cross domain error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using express.js as a backend and backbone.js as a front end and MongoDB as a database. I have no problem fetching single posts or collections of posts based on params I pass in, but whenever I try a POST request I get an error. I have tired to call .save() on my model but, I get a cross site domain error. 
Here is part of my code

```
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: "/posts/new"
});

var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: "/categories/all"
});

var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
  model: new Post(),
  template: JST["post"],
  new_template: JST["new_post"],
  el: $(".page"),

  events: {
    "click .to_category": "updateCurrentCategory",
    "submit .new_post": "create"
  },

  create: function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showLoader();
    console.log("subbmited");
    this.model.save();
    hideLoader();
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the crossdomain policy in your express.js application header section:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");  
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Handle the get for this route
});
```

Then if you are using ajax request to submit the post data you have to set `crossDomain` to `true`.

> If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same
>   domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for
>   example, server-side redirection to another domain. (version added:
>   1.5)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'your/url',
    crossDomain: true, // set it to `true`
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm still having the same problem after putting the above code in my server file and then other in my backbone file. I also tried the backbone .save() function while passing in crossDomain: true, and even tried dataType "jsonp"

Comment: Include this one too: `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still no dice.